# How to edit together split-screen videos?

Tags: video, multimedia, video-editor

with what software i can split the screen of a video? putting like 3 videos at the same time in one video....here is an example of what i want to do
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JynWHMAQrHQ

Comment: Oh yeah they use that technique in the Incredible Hulk, and a few other films....

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the composite transition in [kdenlive](http://kdenlive.org)

```
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

[image]

Watch [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4vXxRgMiLA) to find out how and, as a bonus, how to do a green screen effect.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Kdenlive. Whilst being a professional video editing tool, it's fantastic for beginners.

Comment: @dv3500ea Can't access the video tutorial,it says is private,also the first link you provide is broken.

Comment: It's a private video! Can't watch it.

Answer (score 3):

## How to do this in [openshot](http://www.openshot.org/):

1. Put each clip on a seperate track beneath each other

[image]

2. Right-click clip > properties > layout
3. Set height and Width to 50% set x and y to 0% or 50% depending on location of clip.

## Example for top-left clip

[image: top left clip]

## Example for bottom-right clip

[image: bottom right clip]

## Result

[image]

Comment: With a recent (2.4.3) Openshot, I need to do a right-click, select Properties, then in the pane at the left adjust "Scale X", "Scale Y", "Location X", "Location Y". Note that this should be done at the first frame of the video, otherwise the effect will only happen starting at a specific frame (or with a linear transition).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raiden.net/articles/tutorial_using_cinelerra_to_create_pip_videos/) using Cinelerra.

Unfortunately it seems you have to manually compile it, if you are using the latest Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick Meerkat": http://cinelerra.org/getting_cinelerra.php#ubuntu

Comment: thanx for the answers, i tried cinelerra, is pretty heavy, i follow all the instructions to install it..but it looks ugly, hard to understand, its not comprehensive, you need to guess everything, i think i'll try kdenlive, i feel bad that there are some tutorials for windows movie maker in youtube i hope some people start uploading tutorials of this effect to use it in openshot, and other linux programs, ill watch the kdenlive tutorial

Comment: [carlicuslinux](http://www.youtube.com/user/carlicuslinux) has a few openshot tutorials and [thisweekinlinux](http://www.youtube.com/user/thisweekinlinux) has a set of kdenlive tutorials.